# Getting a directory's path, that is inside an assembly

Tags: asp.net, assemblies, controls

I have a custom asp.net control. That control will also render to the page a piece of javascript. This javascript piece of code is actually properties that have to be initialized. One of this property value must be a path. This path is a directory that is inside this assembly. If it is was a file i would use GetWebResourceUrl but now I don't know what commands to use.

Also I would like to know, if I get the dir path the files inside it will be available for the javascript to use them or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`